# Using select for web scraping in Jsoup

Tags: java, html, web, screen-scraping, jsoup

I'm new to web scraping and my limit is being able to scrape the title of a page in IMDB

I am using this at the moment:

`String contentText = doc.select("title").first().text();`

Which produces the string: `Thor: The Dark World (2013) - IMDb`

If anyone could help me, I am trying to get title and the year as separate strings:

"**Thor: The Dark World**"  "**2013**"

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A cursory glance at the HTML source of the page clearly shows that the required information can be easily extracted via the JSOUP library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if you look at the source for this page you will see further down in the document the following:

```
<h1 class="header">
<span class="itemprop" itemprop="name">Thor: The Dark World</span> 
<span class="nobr">(<a href="/year/2013/?ref_=tt_ov_inf" >2013</a>)</span>    
</h1>
```

So it would seem you can get the required text without any further hacking.

Answer (score 0):

```
String docTitle = doc.select("title").first().text();
String movieName = docTitle.substring(0,docTitle.indexOf("("));
int movieReleaseDate = Integer.parseInt(docTitle.substring(docTitle.indexOf("(")+1,
                                             docTitle.indexOf(")")));
```